# Dynamic coordinate name

Tags: tikz-pgf

The following works fine:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\coordinate (fs-1-2-ne) at (7,8);
\node at (fs-1-2-ne) {Hello};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But, this one does not (it said "Package pgf Error: No shape named fs-1-2 is known"):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\coordinate (fs-1-2-ne) at (7,8);

\pgfmathsetmacro{\prevcoordinate}{3-1};

\node at (fs-1-\prevcoordinate-ne) {Hello};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

My use-case is to get another existing coordinate by name, and the name is obtained from a mathematical expression.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `\pgfmathparse` and then assign `\pgfmathresult` to a macro.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathparse{int(3-1)}
\let\prevcoordinate\pgfmathresult
\coordinate (fs-1-2-ne) at (7,8);

\node at (fs-1-\prevcoordinate-ne) {Hello};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

As noted by percusse, you can use `\pgfmathtruncatemacro` (like `\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\prevcoordinate}{3-1};`)to make your approach work. This will ensure that the output is an integer.

Comment: Use `\pgfmathtruncatemacro` to make it work!! :)

Comment: @percusse Thanks, and I added a note in the answer. :)